# Is there such thing as a conditional operator in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-operator

I have the below SQL code snippet and I want to select sales from all customers by manipulating the value of the @Customer parameter. Is there any way to do this in SQL Server 2008 R2? I've tried setting @Customer = '%' but obviously that didn't work since there is no LIKE operator.

I only want to manipulate the parameter because there will be other times where I will 
need to select only a single customer. Is there such a thing as using an IF/ELSE in the WHERE clause?

```
DECLARE @Customer varchar(5) = ''

SELECT *
FROM SalesData
WHERE Customer=@Customer
```

Comment: Use a `CASE` statement. These can be used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: No LIKE operator? How about Cusomer LIKE @Customer. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: How you determine whether to select single/multiple customer? do you pass specefic values to `@Customer` ??

Comment: I just re-tried using a case statement and it worked. I was using the wrong syntax. Thanks - It is preferable to manipulate only the parameter value so my SQL doesnt end up being much longer

Comment: humpty - my condition would be if @Customer = '' then select all

Comment: Rob - what i meant was the parameter @Customer cant be set to LIKE. I tried adding the following condition in the WHERE clause Customer LIKE @ Customer. That worked when i selected all, but for some reason it didnt  when entering a customer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there such a thing as using an IF/ELSE in the WHERE clause

Absolutely, [there is a `CASE` expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213265%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) - not only in the `WHERE` clause, but also in other parts of your query. However, a more common approach is to use logical expressions in the `WHERE` clause that force SQL Server to take one condition or the other depending on the parameter setting.

> my condition would be `if @Customer = '' then select all`

If you would like to select all customers when the parameter is set to empty, or select all customers where the parameter is not set, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SalesData
WHERE @Customer = ''
   OR  Customer = @Customer
```

If `@Customer` is set to `''`, the first clause of the `OR` expression will be `TRUE` for all rows, so all customers would be returned. However, when `@Customer` is non-empty, the second part of the expression would be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure how you need to perform search

But can try something like below

```
SELECT *
FROM SalesData
WHERE Customer like '%' + @Customer + '%'
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM SalesData
WHERE (LEN(@Customer)>0 AND Customer =@Customer)
     OR (LEN(@Customer)=0)
```

In here I havent `trim` assuming you always pass `''`. But you can always use `LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Customer)))`

Comment: thanks for the answer Humpty- this method also works, i would vote you up if i had enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

If you default `@Customer` to `NULL` rather than `''` then you could just have

```
WHERE Customer = ISNULL(@Customer, Customer)
```

Comment: You guys are all brilliant - thanks so much for all your answers